# Can I modify my name on my Scopus profile page?

Tags: personal-name, scopus

I have recently legally changed my name and about to publish my paper in that new name. However I was wondering is there anyway to change my name on my scopus profile?

Thanks

Comment: @user3209815 I disagree: Scopus is widely used in academia.  Whether this website feature is sufficiently on-topic is somewhat questionable, per [this meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/2219/22733), but it is a simple question and I would be comfortable leaving it open for a little bit to see if anybody has a simple answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I know my university uses scopus rankings for promotions. Their website say nothing and I was wondering if anyone had experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply publish your paper with your new name on it. It will appear in Scopus within your new author profile (with a newly created Scopus Author ID). Finaly, you can send a request to merge authors to Scopus (http://www.scopus.com/feedback/author/home.uri#/). All your Scopus records (with the former and new name) will be collected in a unique author profile. When merging profiles, you should set your newly created profile (with your new name) as preferred.